# append a value to a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have an excel file of three columns.  I want the first column to be the key, then create a list of the next two columns as the values.

However, the .append feature doesn't appear to be working for me

```
d = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row[0]] = row[1]
    d[row[0]].append(row[2])
```

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a unicode object as a dict value and then attempting to call `append` on that unicode object. Instead, you should assign the initial value as a list, as follows:

```
d = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row[0]] = [row[1]]
    d[row[0]].append(row[2])
```

An even better way would be:

```
d[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

or perhaps:

```
a, *b = row
d[a] = b
```

Comment: worked like a charm.  thanks for the pro tips as well, helps me understand better

Comment: actually, the d[row[0]] = row[1:] doesn't work for some reason.  It doesn't select the first row of the current row that is being iterated, but rather the first row in the file. so the output looks like this:title value 0, title value 1, title, value 2 etc